# CSS Grayscale image cannot get header to be a different colour

Tags: html, css, header, grayscale

I am having issues in setting the colour of my header h2 that is on top of a image that I am setting to grayscale. I want it to be orange but as I have added grayscale it is overriding my css to make the h2 text grey.

My html code is the following:

```
<div id="thumbnails" class="pt-page  pt-page-current">
            <div class="scalediv">
                <div class="row no-gutter" data-id="one">
                    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">                            
                                <figure class="callpost" data-num="@Model.Article[i].DataNumber" style="background-image: url('@String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(@Model.Article[i].Picture.Image))');" data-property="border-width" data-from="0" data-to="35px">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <div class="content-wraper">                                            
                                            <h2>@Model.Article[i].Title</h2>                                                                                                                                       
                                            <div class="excerpt">@Model.Article[i].IntroText</div>
                                            <div class="postinfo"> ARTICLES <span>@Convert.ToDateTime(Model.Article[i].DateCreated).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</span> </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </figure>                            
                        </div>
                    }                    
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is my CSS for the grayscale:

```
#thumbnails figure {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;      
}
#thumbnails figure:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
    filter: none !important;    
}
```

I have tried adding to the css like this:

```
#thumbnails figure h2{
    color: #DD2C00 !important;
}
```

This is my CSS for the header:

```
figure .content  h2 {            
    color: #DD2C00;
    font-family: FuturaBT-Medium;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 47px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;                       
}
```

Along with other attempts and trying to change the CSS for the h2 but I cannot get the header to display in orange while the image is in gray scale.

Any ideas or pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: With the code that you have provided here, this is what i get on the snippet: [**link**](https://i.gyazo.com/ebd61905c4b9c261d740de2288eedc8c.png). How could I help you with such a thing?

Comment: As an alternative, instead of nesting, move the content with the <h2> outside `<figure>` and use `position: absolute` to make it appear on top

Comment: I have moved the header outside of the figure but this puts it in the wrong position, i have added in my css for the h2.

Comment: Freestock.tk - I need help with getting the header (h2) to display in the colour of orange when the image is in grayscale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work, because the filters are calculated after the DOM rendering. Therefore, `!important` will have no effect.

To disable the filter effect to h2, you need to bring it out. You can visually put h2 on the figure in different ways, such as a negative margin.

Example:https://jsfiddle.net/j9fbc0sw/3/

Sorry for my English)

Comment: this is great, from your example i can create what i want. many thanks for your help